# Display suite's adding custom fields loads eternally

Tags: 7, entities, display-suite

In "Manage display" page of my *product* content type, I have the custom fields tab. In that tab I have some buttons... None of these buttons works. I tried both but the popup div loads eternally there.

Anyone with the same problem with any clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

all these are the view modes like teaser,full content etc.whenever you create any panel ,there will be tabs of full-content etc...then u can edit the settings displayed below these tabs..here these buttons would be visible...